# Getting error #2032 when calling WCF Service even though call succeeds

Tags: apache-flex, wcf, soap, air

We are developing an application using Adobe Air from the client gui with a mix of WCF and REST on the backend. One of the requirements of this application is that it must work offline. So, when the user clicks save, the application stores it in a local sqlite database. Every 15 seconds, the application checks if it is online, and if so, sends any pending requests out. Then if the call succeeds it updates the local database so it won't try to send that case out again.

For this particular operation - OpenMedicalCase, the app sends out the request and can't decode the response. I am verifying that the WCF side of things is working correctly. The response message is well formed. The network monitor in flashbuilder says I am receiving 100 Continue:

POST /services/medicalcase.svc HTTP/1.1
Referer: app:/AWC_MRDS.swf
Accept: text/xml, application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9,   text/plain;q=0.8, text/css, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif;q=0.8, application/x-shockwave-flash, video/mp4;q=0.9, flv-application/octet-stream;q=0.8, video/x-flv;q=0.7, audio/mp4, application/futuresplash, */*;q=0.5
x-flash-version: 10,1,53,64
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IMedicalCaseService/OpenMedicalCase"
Content-Length: 8534
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/2.0.2
Host: localhost:11934
Cookie: RememberMe=1147670691^1#3435272784175716681

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 23 Dec 2010 21:23:49 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Calls to other operations at the same endpoint are returning 200 OK like expected. So what ends up happening is that flex thinks the call did not succeed and sends it over and over again. AFAIK flex is not sending Expect: 100-Continue in the headers either.

Update: I attached debuggers to the wcf service AND the gui, setting a breakpoint right before the server sends a response. Flex receives 100 Continue before the service code returns anything. Please note that I am only testing this using the ASP.NET development server. Is there some property or configuration option I need to change on the flex side? WCF?

Comment: +! for a well explained question. I don't have an answer, but one warning.  Iif the application is not "active" then the frame rate will be throttled. This was a runtime change in order to improve efficiency.  I've heard stories of people who have problems with this and timers. I doubt it relates to your problem at hand, but it something to be aware of moving forward. You may look into the AIR APIs for telling whether the app is online or offline instead of using timers. Here is some info http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html#1033515

Comment: Another good link on the Network connection APIs of AIR http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/10_tips_building_on_air.html#t6

Comment: I'm using the URL monitor currently. Basically I send a HEAD request to a resource that makes sure the database is up, resolves the services from the IoC container to make sure all the dependencies have been correctly registered, etc. Then I send back 200 OK if all is good.

Comment: Got it!  Good luck; I hope someone can answer your question.